# Date Regex matching with lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match specific dates with regex.

What I **need** to match (without quotes):
-> "September 2020"
-> "September 20"

What should **not** match(!):
-> "21. September 2020"
-> "21 September 20"

So only the Month September and a year **without** any day beforehand!

**What have I tried:**
`(?<![0-9][.]) September [1-4]?[0-9]?[0-9][0-9]`
This regex works fine if the number before the date has a dot (21. September 2020 does not match but 21 September 2020 does). It isn't possible to make the dot an optional match in the lookbefore because "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width".

**Further information**
-> I need to run this regex with PostgreSQL
-> It's no problem that the regex is pretty simple and has a lot of fixed chars. I don't understand / need this regex wizardry which some people are using for matching dates ;)

Has Anyone an idea how a lookbefore would look like to not match both cases (with and without a dot)?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You might use 2 lookbehinds `(?<![0-9][.])(?<![0-9]) September [1-4]?[0-9]?[0-9][0-9]` https://regex101.com/r/GduQsC/1

Comment: I'm an idiot sandwich -.- So concentrated on overthinking the problem that such a simple solution wouldn't come to my mind. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another lookbehind to assert not a digit:

```
(?<![0-9][.])(?<![0-9]) September [1-4]?[0-9]?[0-9][0-9]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GduQsC/1)

If you only want to match 2 or 4 digits after September:

```
(?<![0-9][.])(?<![0-9]) September (?:[1-4][0-9])?[0-9][0-9]\y
```

Where `(?:[1-4][0-9])?` is a non capture group that optionally matches 2 digits, and  `\y` matches at [the beginning or end of a word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE).

Comment: Thanks! But what exactly is the benefit of using this "(?:[1-4][0-9])?[0-9][0-9]\y" instead of my version?

Comment: @Silvan See for example what it could also match https://regex101.com/r/x8E6M3/1 If that is also ok, then you can omit that part.

Comment: Ahh I see. I made an additional code date validation because I can't trust my regex knowledge. But with this solution I think I can scrap that. Thanks!